# CiviContribute: customize "find contributions" default view

Tags: civicontribute, profile, search-results

I'm using CiviCRM 4.7.27 with Wordpress and am trying to figure out how to customize the default results table that is shown when "find contributions" is run. Normally, the search shows a table with the columns: name, amount, type, etc. I would like to customize which columns are shown for the search result but cannot for the life of me figure out how to do this.

I tried to create a profile with the columns I want to view and enabled "Used for: search views". However, when I tried to add a Contributions field to the profile, I got the error "Contribution cannot be used as a result column for profile searches."

Also, supposing I was able to create the profile with the fields that I want, it is not clear how to use it for the search view, since the "find contributions" page does not seem to allow a view to be chosen. Also, the "advanced search" page does not show the profile I created in the "Display Results As Views For Display Contacts" dropdown menu.

Any help would be much appreciated! BTW, this was the reference page I consulted to try to get this feature to work: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Format+Advanced+Search+Result+Columns

Answer (score 2):

Through UI there is no such settings to alter the columns of Components Search results such as Contribution, Membership etc. You can achieve this by using [Search Column hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_searchColumns/).

HTH
Pradeep